# Webservice call 1k times within a short window best practice?

Tags: php, web-services

We are making 1000 requests to a webservice, once daily. Each request takes about 5 seconds to complete. This then will take about 83 minutes to complete.

Our solution is to simply make the request 1000 times and set `set_time_limit` to 0.

Is there a better way to handle this we are missing?

We don't need to complete the 1000 calls withing 83 minutes, it can be done within say 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Make a single call to a new web service method that returns all 1000 records in a single XML result.

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately we are stuck with one web service call for one result.